# Ruby "storing" format string

Tags: ruby, string

How can I store a format string like this

```
s = "test with #{value}"
```

so that later on I can do this

```
puts s % {:value => 'hello'}
```

If I write the first thing, it complains that `value` is not found (true, I want to provide it later). If I use the raw string `s = 'test with #{value}'` it is not interpolated.

I specifically tried this:

```
@format_html = "<a href=\"http://boardgamegeek.com/user/%{who.sub ' ', '+'}\">%{who}</a> receives <a href=\"%{got[0]}\">%{got[1]}</a> from <a href=\"http://boardgamegeek.com/user/%{from.sub ' ', '+'}\">%{from}</a> and sends <a href=\"%{given[0]}\">%{given[1]}</a> to <a href=\"http://boardgamegeek.com/user/%{to.sub ' ', '+'}\">%{to}</a>"
puts @format_html % {:who   => 'who',
                        :given => 'given',
                        :from  => 'from',
                        :got   => 'got',
                        :to    => 'to'}
```

and I get this:

```
KeyError (key{who.sub ' ', '+'} not found):
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works only with ruby 1.9+:

```
s = "test with %{value}"
puts s % { value: 'hello' } # => test with hello
```

Comment: hi. thanks for the answer... i tried it but it doesn't work. would you check my edit? i'm using ruby 1.9.3p327

Comment: well, you can't use ruby code inside `%{}`. It's not the same as `#{}`

Answer (score 0):

The pickaxe http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9 says under `String#%`:

> If the format specification contains more than one substitution, then arg must be an Array containing the values to be substituted.

```
@format_html = "<a href=\"http://boardgamegeek.com/user/%s\">%s</a> receives <a href=\"%s\">%s</a> from <a href=\"http://boardgamegeek.com/user/%s\">%s</a> and sends <a href=\"%s\">%s</a> to <a href=\"http://boardgamegeek.com/user/%s\">%s</a>"
h = {:who   => 'who',
     :given => ['given1', 'given2'],
     :from  => 'from    ',
     :got   => ['got1', 'got2'],
     :to    => 'to     '}
who, given, from, got, to = h.values
who_plus  = who.gsub(' ', '+')
got0      = got[0]
got1      = got[1]
from_plus = from.gsub(' ', '+')
given0    = given[0]
given1    = given[1]
to_plus   = to.gsub(' ', '+')
puts @format_html % [who_plus, who, got0, got1, from_plus, from, given0, given1, to_plus, to]
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb
<a href="http://boardgamegeek.com/user/who">who</a> receives <a href="got1">got2</a> from <a href="http://boardgamegeek.com/user/from++++">from    </a> and sends <a href="given1">given2</a> to <a href="http://boardgamegeek.com/user/to+++++">to     </a>
```